# Go言語でしっかりとreturnを書いてるにも関わらずmissing return at end of functionと表示される

Tags: go

```
func talk(user_input string) string{
  switch true{
    case user_input == "hello":
      return "hello"
  }
}
```

とこのように書いてるにも関わらずmissing return at end of functionと実行したときにエラーになって表示されます。どの様にすれば良いのでしょうか。ちなみにgolangのバージョンはgo 1.10.3 window/amd64です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

値を返すと宣言された関数は、実行時にどのような条件が満たされても、あるいは満されなくとも、`return` を行う必要があります。
質問の例ですと、`user_input == "hello"` が満たされた場合は確かに `return` されますが、その他の場合が問題です。
例えば以下のように、その他の場合にも何かしらの値を `return` するようにします。

```
func talk(userInput string) string {
    switch {
    case userInput == "hello":
        return "hello"
    default:
        return "default"
    }
}
```